# Run time error Library not registered while opening a .doc file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I created a macro in excel vba to process a list of file that I need to copy from a "source path" to a "target path".  When copied I also need to remove the protection of the .doc file.
Everything is working perfectly fine but only on my station.  When I try it on two others stations I get the following error message:
"Run time error '2147319779 (8002801d)'
Automation error
Library not registered"
Here's what I already checked:  I've checked for the VBA references in Excel and Word and they are the same.
From what I can found on other forums it could be some hexkeys problem, but I'm so afraid of playing into this,  and also the solution that was proposed wasn't working (I couldn't find the appropriate reg key on the problem station).
I also tried adding some delay, but still no luck

Here's my code below

```
    Sub copy_file_and_unprotect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim original_name As String
Dim copied_name As String
Dim WdApp As Object
Dim source_path As String
Dim target_path As String
Dim pwd As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Liste de vérification")             'where the original folder is stored
target_path = ws.Cells(1, 6) & "\Sections de devis type"

Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Nom des divisions")
source_path = ws.Cells(4, 5)                            'where the file will be copied
pwd = "cimaqc123"                                   'password to unprotect the file

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Plan de travail")
lig = 11
col = 26

Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

While ws.Cells(lig, col) <> ""                          'loop to copy & unprotect a list of file
    num_sec = ws.Cells(lig, col)
    nom_sec = ws.Cells(lig, col + 2)
    file_name = num_sec & " - " & nom_sec & ".doc"            'name of the original file to be copied

    F = Dir(source_path & "\" & "*.doc")      'loop to search thru the source file for the file "file_name"
    Do While Len(F) > 0
        If F = file_name Then                     '
            original_name = source_path & "\" & F                     'path and name of file to be copied
            copied_name = target_path & "\" & file_name                'path and name of new file to be unlocked later on
            FileCopy original_name, copied_name                         'copying of the file

'-----THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE AFTER THE FOLLOWING LINE-----
            Set WdApp = Documents.Open(copied_name)
            If Not WdApp.ProtectionType = -1 Then                   'unprotect the file
                 WdApp.Unprotect pwd
                 WdApp.Close True
            Else
                WdApp.Close True
            End If
            GoTo file_copied:
        End If
        F = Dir()
    Loop
file_copied:
    lig = lig + 1                        'on passe à la prochaine section de devis

Wend

End Sub
```

Could anyone share some taughts about this?  How can I resolve the error message I get?

Comment: Are they using the same version of Office as you are (2007 vs. 2010) including if its 32bit vs. 64 bit not a 100% sure. But that could be a reason

Comment: Why do you set `WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, and then in your loop repeatedly set `WdApp = Documents.Open(copied_name)`? `WdApp` is your connection to Word, and you throw it away (thus losing the connection to Word), and wonder why you can't automate Word. (And what is `Documents`, anyway? You have no `Documents` variable in your question other than there. I'm presuming you meant `WdApp.Documents`, which of course wouldn't work because you're throwing away your connection to Word in the same statement.)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not as good as you in coding, so I may do stupid things in the process.  I removed the first "set WdApp = CreateObject"  but I still get the same result.  Also this code is an extract of my code so it could be why it looks funny.  But anyway it still crash at that same spot.  Any other taughts you could kindly share?  Also

Comment: @izzymo  Could be the reason.  If so do you have any ideas of what could be the fix for this?  Tx for your input

Comment: The first one is the wrong one to remove. *It's your connection to Word*, as I said previously. Imagine being on the telephone - that phone call is your connection so you can talk to the person on the other end. What your code is doing is dialing the number, immediately hanging up, and then trying to talk to the person on the other end over and over (but you've already hung up on them before the first word was spoken).

Comment: @KenWhite  Ok I think I see where you want to go with this.  So I'll remove the first one.  But then how to I pass the argument "copied_name"  thru WdApp so it will check for the .ProtectionType property of the file?  Or maybe I have everything wrong on how I can modify the .ProtectionType property of a .doc.  Thank you very much for making me a better (wannabe) programmer

Comment: If I'm following what you're trying to do, you should declare a new variable (perhaps `WdDoc`) and assign it a value using `WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open()`, and then perform the further operations using `WdDoc`. Leave the first `WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` in, as it's your connection to Word.

Comment: @KenWhite  Wouhou! You're my hero for the day.  I'll update the posted code with your solution.  Works like a charm on every station now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @KenWhite here's the updated code with error resolved

```
Sub copy_file_and_unprotect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim original_name As String
Dim copied_name As String
Dim WdApp As Object
Dim WdDoc As Object
Dim source_path As String
Dim target_path As String
Dim pwd As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Liste de vérification")             'where the original folder is stored
target_path = ws.Cells(1, 6) & "\Sections de devis type"

Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Nom des divisions")
source_path = ws.Cells(4, 5)                            'where the file will be copied
pwd = "cimaqc123"                                   'password to unprotect the file

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Plan de travail")
lig = 11
col = 26

Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

While ws.Cells(lig, col) <> ""                          'loop to copy & unprotect a list of file
    num_sec = ws.Cells(lig, col)
    nom_sec = ws.Cells(lig, col + 2)
    file_name = num_sec & " - " & nom_sec & ".doc"            'name of the original file to be copied

    F = Dir(source_path & "\" & "*.doc")      'loop to search thru the source file for the file "file_name"
    Do While Len(F) > 0
        If F = file_name Then                     '
            original_name = source_path & "\" & F                     'path and name of file to be copied
            copied_name = target_path & "\" & file_name                'path and name of new file to be unlocked later on
            FileCopy original_name, copied_name                         'copying of the file

'----------------LINE BELOW IS WHERE IT WAS CAUSING PROBLEM -------------------------
            Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(copied_name)       'line that was add
            'Set WdApp = Documents.Open(copied_name)            'line that was removed
            If Not WdDoc.ProtectionType = -1 Then                   'unprotect the file
                 WdDoc.Unprotect pwd                                'replaced WdApp by WdDoc
                 WdDoc.Save
                 WdDoc.Close True
            Else
                WdDoc.Close True
            End If
            GoTo file_copied:
        End If
        F = Dir()
    Loop
file_copied:
    lig = lig + 1
Wend

End Sub
```